# It costs nothing to say

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Suppose a group of researchers claimed that they were working on 7G technology, and someone said, "It **costs** nothing to say you're working on something so advanced. What could "cost" mean here?

I'm considering which of the two senses given by Merriam-Webster is relevant:

> a. to cause (someone) to lose something
>
> b. to cause (someone) to experience something unpleasant

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: IMO, it is closer to (b). It's implying/suggesting that an action should be done because no bad thing will happen anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. It's talking about cost in the sense of money or effort.

Comment: I've changed the example. Would you reconsider your reply?

Comment: No, although the new example isn't something anyone would actually say.